# How to hide more than one navigation item in Wayfinder- Modx (evolution )

Tags: navigation, modx

I'm using Wayfinder to create navigation in Modx(evo) and below is the code which is working fine except i'm not able to hide more than one navigation item:

```
[[
Wayfinder? &startId=`0`  
&parentRowTpl=`Firstlevel-NavItem`
&outerTpl=`Outer-Nav` 
&innerTpl=`Firstlevel-Nav`
&rowTpl=`Inner-Row`  
&excludeDocs='1,136' 
]]
```

&excludeDocs, it only works for first number specified. (In above case only 1 navigation item is hidden, nav(136) is visible.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You really use ' instead ` in excludeDocs argument?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use backticks around snippet parameter, not single quotes, so the code should look like this:

```
[[
Wayfinder? &startId=`0`  
&parentRowTpl=`Firstlevel-NavItem`
&outerTpl=`Outer-Nav` 
&innerTpl=`Firstlevel-Nav`
&rowTpl=`Inner-Row`  
&excludeDocs=`1,136`
]]
```